# Wait for a buffered channel to be full

Tags: go

I must have missed something because I haven't found the answer online for this pretty basic problem. I am using a buffered channel capable of holding three `int` values.

I am then using three goroutines to fill it up and I want to do an operation once the buffered channel is full.

Here is a snippet explaining the problem:

```
func main() {
    // Initialization of the slice a and 0 < n < len(a) - 1.
    difs := make(chan int, 3)
    go routine(a[:n], difs)
    go routine(a[n + 1:], difs)
    go routine(a[n - 1:n + 1], difs)

    fmt.Println(<-difs) // Display the first result returned by one of the routine.
}

func routine(a []int, out chan<- int) {
    // Long computation.
    out <- result
}
```

I would like to update my code so that `fmt.Println(<-difs)` displays an array of `int` when all the values have been computed. I could use three times `<-difs` but I wonder if Go offers something cleaner to do that.

Comment: Maybe you should use a [select](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- you generally don't wait for a channel to be full, since you can't then concurrently consume values from it. You want to wait for the goroutines to complete, which is what you use a sync.WaitGroup for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wait using channel itself, like this working sample code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12} // Initialization of the slice a and 0 < n < len(a) - 1.
    difs := make(chan int, 3)

    go routine(a[0:4], difs)
    go routine(a[4:8], difs)
    go routine(a[8:12], difs)

    result := []int{<-difs, <-difs, <-difs}

    fmt.Println(result) // Display the first result returned by one of the routine.
}

func routine(a []int, out chan<- int) {
    result := 0 // Long computation.
    for _, v := range a {
        result += v
    }
    out <- result
}
```

output:

```
[10 42 26]
```

Comment: Simple yet effective, thank you! I upvote the other answer as it uses `sync.WaitGroup`, a solution that seems the standard one for this kind of problem.

Comment: @armand-grillet no need for sync.WaitGroup here for just 3 channels, you may use channel itself to sync.

Comment: Waitgroups are particularly ideal when you have a variable number of messages being written, because they can be added to and subtracted from as you fire up new goroutines and as they complete.

Comment: Also you may use:  `result := make([]int, 3)
 for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
  result[i] = <-difs
 }` for more channels.

Comment: Downside is that the receive routine will block indefinitely if one of the sender routines returns before sending.  With the waitgroup version using a deferred `wg.Done()`, this can't happen.

Comment: also you may use `defer` with channels too, like this: `
 defer func() { out <- result }()`

Comment: You can, but that still requires you to send as many values over the routine as you have routines, even if some of those sends are basically just sentinel values that indicate something went wrong.  Waitgroups allow routines to indicate that they have completed without actually having to sent junk data over the output channel.

Answer (score 6):

The function `len()` supports channels, returning the number of unread queued elements within the channel.  However, you'll have to run a loop to periodically check it.

The traditional method of handling this is using a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup), as so:

```
func main() {
    // Initialization of the slice a and 0 < n < len(a) - 1.
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(3)
    difs := make(chan int, 3)
    go routine(a[:n], difs, &wg)
    go routine(a[n + 1:], difs, &wg)
    go routine(n - 1:n + 1], difs, &wg)

    wg.Wait() // blocks until wg.Done() is called 3 times
    fmt.Println(<-difs) // Display the first result returned by one of the routine.
}

// NOTE: This MUST accept a POINTER to the waitgroup.  They are not copy-safe.
func routine(a []int, out chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    // Long computation.
    out <- result
}
```